# Importing a CSV file into R

Tags: r, csv

I am Using a MACbook and new to R. I have the social network file on my desktop and I'm trying to get R to read it. I saved it as CSV

command typed:

```
sn.csv <- read.csv("C:\Users\Opemipo Akinosun\Desktop\social_network.csv", header = T)
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Opemipo Akinosun/Desktop/social_network.csv': No such file or directory
```

the resource I'm learning with doesn't ask me to set my directory so I'm a little reluctant to doing that as suggested

Comment: you have to set the correct path to your file. `C:/` is definitely not a MAC directory

Comment: Try `sn <- read.csv(file.choose())`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `file.path` that is OS-independant :

```
ff <- file.path("C:","Users","Opemipo Akinosun","Desktop","social_network.csv")
```

Then you can check if the file exists:

```
> file.exists(ff)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Here is the result I got from using the info you provided, looks like I assigned ff to something                                                                                 [1] "C:/Users/Opemipo Akinosun/Desktop/social_network.csv"

Comment: I did get a false whin i used the file.exist(ff) command. does that indicate that the file doesn't exist?

Comment: yes this means that the file with this pas does note exist.

Answer (score 0):

I worked and I could resolve the issue I was facing. Try changing the directory and then use the above code. So it will be as below

```
setwd("C:/Users/user/Desktop")
sn <- read.csv("social_network.csv" , header = TRUE)
sn
```

Run the above command and you should be all set to work further.